# Error in installing packages in termux kali distribution

Tags: linux, bash, kali-linux

I had installed Kali Debian in `termux`, where I got an error while installing `python3`.

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a'
> to correct the problem.

Unfortunately got another error after execution.

> Setting up udisks2 (2.8.1-4) ...
>
> Failed to scan devices: No such file or directory dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
> installed udisks2 package post-installation script subprocess returned
> error exit status 1
>
> Setting up man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
>
> debconf: unable to
> initialize frontend: Dialog debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is
> installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at
> /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
>
> debconf: falling
> back to frontend: Readline Building database of manual pages ...
> ./tracee/event.c:517: int handle_tracee_event(Tracee *, int):
> assertion "!IS_IN_SYSENTER(tracee)" failed proot warning: signal 6
> received from process 26023

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who had gave an eye to my question, although i find out my solution.
Firstly remove all the related files by 
rm -rf 
command.
Then run the installation command to reinstall kali in termux.
Hopefully i find out my apt-get working fine with all the commands.